# How can I get this Javascript to redirect to a new URL?

Tags: javascript, authentication, login-script

I am very new to this, I am trying to get a very simple password field that redirects to a URL in the same window when the submitted password matches the stored password. I know this isn't secure at all, it doesn't need to be. Below is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function pwcheck() {
        var pw = document.form.password.value;
        if (pw=="hello") {
            location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        else {
            alert('Login incorrect');
        }
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't need to be secure, why are you using it?

Comment: @icktoofay homework maybe? lol

Comment: If you wanted it to be even a tiny bit more secure, you could hash the password and encrypt the final URL with the password. Then when the user tries to authenticate, you hash what they entered and compare that with the precomputed hash. If the hashes match, decrypt the final URL with the password they entered and redirect there. (but I'd still do it on the server-side if possible; otherwise they can brute-force your hash)

Comment: In the check-that-the-power-is-on department, are you sure your function is even being run? Your quoted source shows only a definition.

Comment: How is `pwcheck()` being called?

Comment: <input type="image" value="Log In" name="login" id="login" src="images/login.png" onclick="pwcheck()" /> is the code where it is called. And it's definitely being run, the alert pops up with incorrect passwords, with the correct password the page just reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page reloads because the button is submitting the page. Cancel the click. There are a couple of ways of doing it, the easiest in your case is adding return fasle to the click event.

```
<input type="image" value="Log In" name="login" id="login" src="images/login.png" onclick="pwcheck(); return false;" />
```